# Converting a theme to Gutenberg but some styles are missing in the front end

Tags: block-editor

I have come accross a bit of a problem when converting a theme to gutenberg - I have done this plenty of times before and never come accross this issue. Having added the relevant theme support e.g.

```
add_theme_support( 'responsive-embeds' );
add_theme_support( 'wp-block-styles' );

add_theme_support( 'align-wide' );

add_editor_style( 'css/editor-style.css' );
add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );
```

I can see the block styles in the editor for the most part but it also has this error :
[image: errors showing]

I am using the Block Unit Test before converting the rest of the pages but I need to sort this error first...

There are no styles or classes being added to the blocks on the front end
Blocks that are affected :
Images 
H1 Headings 
Blockquotes
Images
Pull quotes and a few others

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: to elaborate on the issue for example the Heading 1 block doesn't display front end with <h1> tags its just text but the rest of the headings display fine

Comment: The issue seems to be with the JavaScript of those saved blocks. When the editor loads, it reads the content HTML, recognizes a certain block and tries to find its JavaScript block type registration. So either the plugin that loads that JS is missing (you need to add the plugin that register those block types) or the content from those blocks is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED -- it was a plugin conflict from a very old custom plugin that was on there - turns out its key to the build of the site though so time to figure out which part of the plugin is conflicting

Comment: Hello and thank you for coming back and posting an answer to your solution. Since this ended up being a plugin conflict and something that is specific to your website & install I'm going to vote to close this question as it may not help future readers.